# SVN having credential problems with Jenkins running as SYSTEM

Tags: python, svn, windows-7, credentials, jenkins

I have Jenkins running a python script that makes some SVN calls, my problem is that Jenkins tries to run this script as SYSTEM user which doesn't seem to have permission to access the SVN. It prompts me for a password for 'SYSTEM' upon my svn call.

If I run the python script by itself, I have no problems accessing the repository. Is there a way to have Jenkins run its Windows batch command as a non-SYSTEM user? I would rather not hardcode the SVN username and password in my script.

Edit: I found a way to change the user Jenkins runs under, it is accessed through:
Start > Control Panel > Administrative Tools > Services > Right Click, Properties for jenkins > Log On.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a new Jenkins job, and use Subversion as the revision control system. Put in the URL of the Subversion repository you want to manipulate in your Python script. Under the URL will appear a link to let you set the login. Click the link and log in.

Once you're done, you can delete the job. The whole purpose was to allow Jenkins to set up Subversion to allow that user to login in for that repository URL.

Comment: Cool, this seems to be what I was looking for. Also, if you already have SVN access but want to explicitly give a username and password for Jenkins to use, click the question mark next to Repository URL field and click "this link" to set that.